# Understanding memory allocation for named returned type

Tags: go

In the following code sample, can I assume that I don't need to allocate the returned value? Will the compiler always allocate any function's named returned value?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Point struct {
    X, Y int
}

func MakePoint(x, y int) (pt Point) {
    pt.X = x
    pt.Y = y
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", MakePoint(1, 2))
}
```

Also, why do I need to add the `return` statement at the end of the function? Is this a bug with the compiler?

If I decide to return a pointer:

```
func MakePoint(x, y int) (pt *Point) {
```

The code will compile but I am getting a runtime error! Why is the compiler letting me believe an allocation with a statement such as `pt = new(Point)` is not needed? Is this another bug with the compiler? Clearly, I am missing something crucial about memory allocation in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the compiler always allocate any function's named returned value?

Yes, absolutely.

> Also, why do I need to add the return statement at the end of the function? Is this a bug with the compiler?

Because function which return a value must end in a return statement. That's what the language spec requires and the compiler enforces.

> Why is the compiler letting me believe an allocation with a statement such as pt = new(Point) is not needed?

The compiler allocates space for the pointer (that's what you return) but he cannot know where the memory for the actual Point shall be. That's your job.

> Is this another bug with the compiler?

No. Such stuff is fundamental. The chances you discover such a bug in such obvious code is basically zero.

Comment: Thanks. It 'clicked' when you explained the difference between pointer allocation and struct allocation. And because go doesn't differentiate between pointer and non-pointer for field access, I guess the statement will still work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> In the following code sample, can I assume that I don't need to allocate the returned value? Will the compiler always allocate any function's named returned value?

I assume by allocate you don't mean assigning like this:

```
a := func(1,2)
```

In this case, compiler will assign whatever comes out of func to a.

But I think you mean allocating function result variables.

```
1. Yes, in this case you don't need to allocate as this is just a value.

2. Nope. It depends whether value is a pointer or a concrete type. In concrete type, you don't need to allocate in any case.
```

> Also, why do I need to add the return statement at the end of the function? Is this a bug with the compiler?

Now to return part, according to standard:

> If the function's signature declares result parameters, the function body's statement list must end in a terminating statement.

And this result can be named or not.

> The code will compile but I am getting a runtime error! Why is the
>   compiler letting me believe an allocation with a statement such as pt
>   = new(Point) is not needed? Is this another bug with the compiler?

It isn't a bug. It's happening because compiler doesn't care about which concrete type a pointer's point. Its create a pointer with zero value of nil. You need to take care of it. Otherwise, you get nil pointer dereference as you still haven't pointed it to any concrete type.